# I need to export certain fields from AD but need to avoid results from child OUs

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export

My current script is:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Employees,DC=MYCompany,DC=local" -Properties * | Select-Object Displayname,Department,Mobile | where-object { ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Disabled Accounts,*") -or ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Email ID,*") -or ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=Resources,*") -or ($_.DistinguishedName -notlike "*OU=TEMPDISABLED,*")} | export-csv -path C:\writable\userexport.csv
```

It works, just not as intended. I keep getting results from the 4 OUs listed that are inside of the "MyCompany" OU.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

That's what the [`-SearchScope`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-searchscope) parameter is for. Just set it to `OneLevel`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase "OU=Employees,DC=MYCompany,DC=local" -Properties * |
    Select-Object Displayname,Department,Mobile |
    where-object { ($.DistinguishedName -notlike "OU=Disabled Accounts,") -or ($.DistinguishedName -notlike "OU=Email ID,") -or ($.DistinguishedName -notlike "OU=Resources,") -or ($.DistinguishedName -notlike "OU=TEMPDISABLED,")} |
    export-csv -path C:\writable\userexport.csv
```

The default is `SubTree`, which searches all child containers. The other option is `Base`, which only returns the object at the `SearchBase` (which does have its uses).

Comment: That was too easy for you. That's awesome! It worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for the help. I was able to get rid of the where-object line.

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchScope OneLevel -SearchBase "OU=Employees,DC=MYCompany,DC=local" -Properties * |
    Select-Object Displayname,Department,Mobile |
    export-csv -path C:\writable\userexport.csv
```

This was what I used.